# Is it necessary to use the keyword ORG in an assembly program?

Tags: assembly, x86, directive, emu8086

In some assembly programs it is not necessary to use the `ORG` directive.

Is there any situation where we *must use* `ORG` in our program?
Where would I need to write `ORG 100H`?

Comment: In a `.com` executable with any data labels, `org 100h` is necessary for the assembler to know the right absolute `offset` when you write `mov ax, [foo]`.  It's not necessary for relative jumps / calls.

Comment: Some assemblers are aware that COM programs always start at offset 100H. Explicit specification of origin is not necessary when they are told that `Program format=COM` is required, see this [example](https://euroassembler.eu/eatests/t7457.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note:* This answer is specific to the usage of `ORG` in MASM and compatible assemblers. The behaviour explained in this answer doesn't sound very smart in hindsight, so later assemblers like NASM handle repositioning inside the output chunk in a different way.

The `ORG` directive serves two different purposes. It can relocate the "current output address" within the currently generated output, for example:

```
init_code:
    PUSH CS      ; tiny memory model, even in EXE file
    POP  DS
    MOV  AH,30h
    INT  21h     ; get DOS version
    CMP  AL, 3
    JAE  DOS_new_enough
    MOV  DX, offset error
    MOV  AH, 9
    INT  21h
error db "Needs DOS 3.0 or newer", 13, 10, '$'
new_enough:
    ; some program code

ORG init_code
var1 dw ?
var2 dw ?
```

to overlay the variables `var1` and `var2` over `init_code`. As `init_code` will no longer be needed after the DOS version has been checked, that memory can later be reclaimed for different purposes.

You can also use `ORG` to assist with self-modifying code, like this:

```
    MOV [WORD PTR CS:LPT_BASE], 278h  ; LPT2
...
    MOV AL, [some_data]
    MOV DX, 378h
    ORG $-2   ; 2 bytes backwards, so the address of the value "378h"
LPT_BASE DW ?
    OUT DX, AL
```

These invocations of `ORG` can be rewritten in different ways.

Another purpose of `ORG` is to tell the linker the target offset for the part of a segment in the output file. If there is no `ORG` directive, the linker just lets the first chunk for a named segment start at offset 0, and each later chunk starts at the end of the previous chunk. Let's say you have two source files assembled separately and then linked together:

```
DATA SEGMENT
my_data db 180h DUP 0
DATA ENDS
END
```

and

```
DATA SEGMENT
my_data2 db 80h DUP 0FFh
DATA ENDS
END
```

The linker will put `my_data` at offset 0 into the data segment, and `my_data2` at offset 180h, so the total data segment size will be 200h.

Now we could put an `ORG` directive into the first assembly file, making it look like:

```
DATA SEGMENT
    ORG 100h
my_data db 180h DUP 0
DATA ENDS
END
```

Now, the linker will assign the offset 100h to `my_data`, and allocate the space between offset 100h and 280h to `my_data`.   `my_data2` will be allocated at 280h. The total data segment size is still 200h, but it uses offsets 100h to 300h, instead of 0 to 200h.

On the other hand, if you use the original first file, and add an `ORG 100h` directive to the second file, `my_data` will be allocated at 0, and `my_data2` will be forced to be allocated at 100h, overlapping the last 80h bytes of `my_data`.

This use of the `ORG` directive, telling the linker to force placement of segment chunks is not achievable by other means.

The most common use of `ORG` is the `ORG 100h` you cite in your question. You use that directive to tell the assembler/linker system, that the contents of this file are to be loaded at offset 100h in the runtime segment. This is how COM programs in DOS are set up: The first 256 bytes contain management data for the operating system and the command line (which can be re-used as 128-byte data transfer buffer), and the program code starts after it. So `ORG 100h` forces the toolchain to build a program that fits the memory layout of COM programs.

Comment: Caveat for future readers: not all assemblers handle ORG the same way, e.g. NASM doesn't support rewinding to overlay like that. (https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc8.html#section-8.1.1).  I think this answer does apply to EMU8086 specifically, and probably to MASM whose syntax it generally uses.

Comment: @PeterCordes Fair point, I added a disclaimer to the answer that it applies to MASM-like assemblers only.